# Can you take the derivative of a function inside of an integral?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I was trying to prove the differentiation property of the fourier transform:

$$x(t) = 1/(2\pi)\int_{-\infty}^\infty X(jw)e^{jwt}dw$$ Then take the derivative of both sides:

$$dx(t)/dt = 1/(2\pi)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d(X(jw)e^{jwt}}{dt}dw = 1/(2\pi)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} X(jw)*jw*e^{jwt}dw$$ However, I'm not sure about the rules for this. Is it legal for me to take the derivative of a function depending on a variable "w" when it is in the integral? Am I allowed to manipulate functions dependent on the variable of integration?

Comment: The conditions, technical terms, etc. may be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: It's an integration rule named after Leibniz, not a rule for Leibniz integrals (which I'm not sure is a thing).

Comment: @eyeballfrog haha you're right I confused it with lebesgue integral.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Unfortunately, the article in the link does not discuss integrating under an improper integral.  I've posted an answer that discusses sufficient conditions and provides examples in which differentiation under the integral fails.  -Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are sufficient conditions for differentiating under an improper integral.

Let $I$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $t\in I$.  If $f(t,\omega)$ and $\frac{\partial f(t,\omega)}{\partial t}$ are continuous for all $t\in I$ and $\omega\in \mathbb{R}$, and if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t,\omega)\,d\omega$ converges for some $t_0\in I$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial f(t,\omega)}{\partial t}\,d\omega$ converges uniformly for all $t\in I$, then

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t,\omega)\,d\omega=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial f(t,\omega)}{\partial t}\,d\omega \tag 1$$

for $t\in I$.

So, let $f(t,\omega)=X(j\omega)e^{j\omega t}$.

Note that the equality in $(1)$ is not true in general.  Here are two examples, which shows that differentiation under the integral sign fails.

---

**EXAMPLE $1$**

For a first example, the integral $I(x)$ as given by

$$I(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}\,dt$$

converges uniformly for all $|x|\ge \delta>0$.  But the integral of the derivative with respect to $x$, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \cos(xt)\,dt$ diverges for all $x$.

---

**EXAMPLE $2$**

As another example, let $J(x)$ be the integral given by

$$J(x)=\int_0^\infty x^3e^{-x^2t}\,dt$$

Obviously, $J(x)=x$ for all $x$ and hence $J'(x)=1$.  However,

$$\int_0^\infty (3x^2-2x^4t)e^{-x^2t}\,dt=\begin{cases}1&,x\ne 0\\\\0&,x=0\end{cases}$$

Thus, formal differentiation under the integral sign leads to an incorrect result for $x=0$ even though all integrals involved are absolutely convergent.

---